# How to set video resolution?

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm working with aForge and I'm attempting to set the resolution for a video feed from an USB webcam so it fits properly in a pictureBox. I'm aiming for a resolution of 800x600, but the default resolution I get is about 640x480. When I try to set the resolution, I get the message that "members of readonly field cannot be modified". Does anyone with experience with aForge have any ideas/a solution?

Comment: readonly should tell you that there could be a Constructor which allows setting your resolution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Exactly: the `desiredFrameSize` property is obsolete. You must use the `VideoResolution` property; for example, using resolution number 0:

```
yourvideoSource.VideoResolution = yourvideoSource.VideoCapabilities[0];
```

The number of the array represents a different resolution.

Use the following command to determine the amount of available resolutions and dimensions:

```
yourvideoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < yourvideoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++ ){

    string resolution= "Resolution Number "+Convert.Tostring(i);
    string resolution_size = yourvideoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But, there is not `VideoResolution ` property in videoSource object

Comment: VideoResolution  is a object from the class VideoCaptureDevice.

Comment: you are sıuch a life saver, such a relief for me my friend, thanks a lot for sharing

Answer (score 0):

How about setting

```
yourvideoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(800, 600);
```

Comment: I wish, but according to aForge, the desiredFrameSize property is obsolete, so I have to use VideoResolution instead, which isn't so simple, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the index according to the capabilities of your `VideoCaptureDevice`

```cs
const int IDX = 0; // change this
_videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(CurrentDevice.MonikerString)
{
    VideoResolution = new VideoCaptureDevice(CurrentDevice.MonikerString).VideoCapabilities[IDX]
};
```

*The previous tips didn't help me so I spent some time to figure it out*