# C# Camera Aforge change resolution setting

Tags: c#, camera, webcam, resolution, aforge

Before this is made a duplicate thread, please don't because the answers on [How to set video resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433853/how-to-set-video-resolution) are useless and do not work AND my question and code is different.

I have looked around on sites but there isn't anything that helps.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection VCD;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FV;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VCD = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        foreach (FilterInfo VCD in VCD)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(VCD.Name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        FV = new VideoCaptureDevice();

/*THE CODE WHICH DOESNT WORK
        for (int i = 0; i < FV.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
        {
            string resolution = "Resolution Number " + Convert.ToString(i);
            string resolution_size = FV.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.ToString();
            comboBox2.Items.Add(resolution_size); //add resolution options in this combobox
        }*/
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //START / STOP CAMERA CODE
    }

    private void FV_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = video;
    }

    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TAKE PHOTO
        pictureBox1.Image.Save("Photos\\capture1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to add a setting to change resolution because the default is just 480p.

Comment: How can this code work if your `FV` is separated from a video input device, while it has to be derived from specific camera instance.

Comment: I don't know. It just does